# Access Apple Watch's microphone

Tags: watchkit

Now that more and more documentation on the Apple Watch is surfacing has anybody found a way to access and use the device's microphone?

Answer (score 12):

You can access the  Watch's microphone on watchOS 2.

**1) Create a file URL at which to store the recorded output.**

```
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *path = [[filePaths firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"rec.m4a"];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

You may specify the extensions .wav, .mp4, and .m4a.

**2) Call the method as follows:**

```
[self presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:fileUrl
                                            preset:WKAudioRecordingPresetWideBandSpeech
                                   maximumDuration:5.0
                                       actionTitle:@"Some Title"
                                        completion:^(BOOL didSave, NSError * __nullable error) {

                                            NSLog(@"didSave:%d, error:%@", didSave, error);
                                        }];
```

You can choose preset in addition to the above

- WKAudioRecordingPresetNarrowBandSpeech
- WKAudioRecordingPresetHighQualityAudio

**In Swift:**

```
self.presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL(
    self.recFileURL(),
    preset: WKAudioRecordingPreset.WideBandSpeech,
    maximumDuration: 5.0,
    actionTitle: "SomeTitle") { (didSave, error) -> Void in

        print("didSave:\(didSave), error:\(error)")
}
```

You can play the recorded file as follows:

```
self.presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL(
    fileURL,
    options: nil) { (didPlayToEnd, endTime, error) -> Void in

        print("didPlayToEnd:\(didPlayToEnd), endTime:\(endTime), error:\(error)")
}
```

You can check the detail specification [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW93).

Comment: I hope there will also be some realtime access to microphone buffer, like one you have when using CoreAudio

Comment: Could you please show us how to make the url in Swift? I'm getting "Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.watchkit.errors error 3.)"" & I feel its because i'm not making the URL correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to record without using the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a specific mention of it in the official documentation but on the [Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1106961#1106961) word from the mods is that it isn't currently possible.

> WatchKit currently doesn't provide access to the watch's microphone. You do, however, have access to the iPhone's microphone from the WatchKit extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for dictation, here are some early findings on the SDK:
http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-text-input-dictation-api/

Obviously, cannot be tested until the hardware is out :D

Answer (score 0):

I think there are good news from the WWDC 2015 and the new watchOS 2 beta:

[image: WWDC watchOS]

Unfortunately, at the moment there is noting about audio in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is introduced in Watch OS 2.

But as Apple mentioned, this part of the API is in preview, and it did changed a lot. As for Watch OS 2 beta 5, the according interface(in Swift) changed to:

> @available(watchOS 2.0, *)
>
> public func presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL(URL: NSURL, preset:
>   WKAudioRecorderPreset, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, completion:
>   (Bool, NSError?) -> Void)

So please always refer to the SDK document you are using, if you want to try this new feature.

By the way, this sample project would be a good start:

https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler

Still, some of the API used in sample is already changed, like this recording one.

Answer (score 0):

This is inside of an action from a button previously added in your Interface.storyboard, also don't forget to add the Privacy - Microphone Usage Description string in the info.plist.

```
@IBAction func btnActionRecord() {
    var filePath: NSURL!
    if let dir: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .allDomainsMask, true).first as NSString? {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent("myRecord.wav")
        filePath = NSURL(string: path)
        let audioOptions = [
            WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsActionTitleKey: "Save",
            WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsAlwaysShowActionTitleKey: true,
            WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsAutorecordKey: true,
            WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey: 5.0] as [String : Any]

        presentAudioRecorderController(withOutputURL: filePath! as URL, preset: .highQualityAudio, options: audioOptions, completion: {
            (didSave, error)  -> Void in
            if didSave {
                print("Audio saved")
                let options = [WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey: true]
                self.presentMediaPlayerController(with: self.filePath as URL, options: options) {
                (didPlayToEnd, endTime, error) -> Void in
                    if didPlayToEnd {
                        print("Audio finished")
                    }
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!.self)
                        }
                }
            }
            if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }

}
```