# How does Shazam on the Apple Watch work? (Microphone access)

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

Shazam on the Apple Watch appears to use the microphone on the watch and somehow stream that data to the iPhone companion app for recognition in the cloud.

The question is, does Shazam have some special deal with Apple to access a private API or can anyone write an app that streams audio to the companion app.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963024/access-apple-watch-microphone?rq=1

Comment: Siri's "what's that song" command gets its answers from Shazam, so I'd suspect they have a deal. http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/19/siri-partners-with-shazam-to-recognize-songs-in-ios-8

Answer (score 2):

Shazam doesn't have special access to the microphone. The description on the Apple site even mentions that it simply activates the microphone on the user's iPhone. http://www.apple.com/watch/app-store-apps/

Comment: Thanks.  That explains why, even though I hold my watch up to the speaker, it won't recognize songs when my phone is in my pants pocket.