# How to access microphone of Apple Watch (i.e. get PCM samples) in real time

Tags: avfoundation, watchkit, audio-recording, microphone, watchos-2

I think about writing a Watch App to record and process audio samples in real time, but I'm unsure if that's possible with WatchOS 2.0.

I found a related question (including an answer) right here:

[Access Apple Watch's microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963024/access-apple-watchs-microphone)

But this is not what I want, I don't want to wait until the recording is finished then look at it. I need to react to the received audio stream in real time.

Is there any way this could be done? Do you guys (and gals) think the file-based method that I linked to could be exploited by trying to read the recording file (as it is being written) from a different thread?

I would love to know. Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Interesting question. Note that Shazam "appears" to be doing what you want, although it's possible they are just messaging the iPhone to pick up the audio.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I will check out the app.

Comment: Anything new on this?